# when navigate or redirect to other page by clicking link codeigniter does not load css and js

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

when navigate or redirect to other page by clicking link codeigniter does not load css and js

my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

my routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'signup';
$route['login_control/(:any)'] = 'login_control';
$route['upload_photo/(:any)'] = 'upload_photo';
$route['search_profile_controller/(:any)'] =   'search_profile_controller';
$route['search_profile_controller/profile_clicked'] = 'search_profile_controller/profile_clicked';
$route['profileclick/(:any)'] = 'profileclick';
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

Comment: Add `<base href="/" />` to the head section of your html.

Comment: can you show how you are loading the css files??

Comment: Use `base_url()` function to load public files i.e. `base_url('assets/css/style.css'); base_url('assets/images/landscape.jpg');`.

Comment: Thank you very much to all of you!! My problem has solved .